# PhoneGap Android Error "create.bat exit code 8"

Tags: node.js, cordova, ant

Iam followed a guide to create my first project on PhoneGap and I wanted to run it on a Android Emulator. So I typed

```
phonegap run android
```

Some stuff loaded but than I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\form>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:4
7:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
{ [Error: C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Comm
and failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
   [error] C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Com
mand failed with exit code 8
```

EDIT:

After following the instructions I installed ant and didnt get the error anymore. But there are still some other errors:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\form>phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13){ [Error: C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
   [error] C:\Users\Thomas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
```

EDIT2: Ok I solved the problem. I needed to install JAVA JDK, Android SDK and assign some environmental variables...

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the `ant` manually from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

Then extract it somewhere. Suppose in drive `D:\apache-ant-1.9.3`

Next add the environment variable `ANT_HOME` with it's value `D:\apache-ant-1.9.3`

Lastly add this to path variable `%ANT_HOME%\bin`

Don't forget to restart terminal or command prompt

Comment: Hey this worked at least Iam not getting any ant errors anymore...but now I get a bunch of other errors =/ Edited in my startpost

Comment: @user3592991 You need to add path of `tools` & `platform-tools` folders' in path variable which are inside your extracted Android SDK. You also need to add the `Java JDK bin` folder path into path variable if they are not automatically added after installation.

Comment: Yes that was missing :) But now it works fine thanks

Comment: I had the same error... it was actually because in config.xml I had version="0.0.1a" and it didn't like it since 0.0.1a is not a number... confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to a generic error without much description on its own. For me I am consistently seeing this build error if I set the app configuration to portrait only using a VS 2015 RC Cordova project.